# how to import ng-file-upload

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ng-file-upload

I am trying to import module from `@types/ng-file-upload/index.d.ts` which contains

```
declare var angularFileUploadDefaultExport: string;
export = angularFileUploadDefaultExport;

declare module 'angular' {
    export namespace angularFileUpload {
        interface ImageDimensions {

        }
    }
}
```

now if i import it like below

```
    import * as ngFileUpload from 'ng-file-upload';
    or
    import 'ng-file-upload';
    or
    import ngFileUpload = require('ng-file-upload');
```

but webpack is still giving error while trying to access      `ngFileUpload.ImageDimensions`

what is the correct way to import packages defined with `module`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given that it is defined inside the angular modules `declare module 'angular' {` there is no need to import it... just directly use it as `angular.angularFileUpload`